# python subprocess Popen behaving differently on local and remote system

Tags: python, django, travis-ci

I am using django and sending a build to travis-ci which is failing the build on my tests. The line that is in question is in this function...

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def make_mp3(path, blob):
    process = Popen(
        ['lame', '-', '--comp', '40', path], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout_data = process.communicate(input=blob.read())
    return stdout_data
```

the line that calls the function is here:

```
make_mp3(mp3_path, request.FILES['audio_file'])
```

on my local system the tests run fine and pass. I have been using this function for a while and it always behaves as expected. But when I send it to travis-ci for a build it gives me this traceback...

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_post_upload_audio_word (define.tests.ViewTests)
Testing the audio upload function for word audio
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/build/deltaskelta/langalang/define/tests.py", line 827, in test_post_upload_audio_word
    'audio_file': audio_file})
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 541, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 343, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 409, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 494, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/travis/build/deltaskelta/langalang/define/views.py", line 21, in dispatch
    return super(Define, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/build/deltaskelta/langalang/define/views.py", line 89, in post
    return upload_audio(request, context)
  File "/home/travis/build/deltaskelta/langalang/define/views_func.py", line 251, in upload_audio
    make_mp3(mp3_path, request.FILES['audio_file'])
  File "/home/travis/build/deltaskelta/langalang/define/views_func.py", line 25, in make_mp3
    ['lame', '-', '--comp', '40', path], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/opt/python/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/opt/python/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I cannot see why this would pass the test on my system and fail on the build. The input file is obviously there because `request.FILES` found it. The directory exists..I checked. So what is it telling me doesn't exist?

Comment: What if you execute it manually on production (if you can)? Thing is that this   exception can refer not to path parameter, but to command you execute

Comment: You posted this right as I figured it out. I forgot to install lame in the build environment. How did you know that could also be the problem? I spend hours going over the same lines again and again checking paths because I thought that is what it was telling me

Comment: I tried to explain it in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason it fails: execution command can't execute non-existent file. It's `lame` in your example. Quote from [doc section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#exceptions):

> The most common exception raised is OSError. This occurs, for example, when trying to execute a non-existent file. Applications should prepare for OSError exceptions.

You also could check source code for `_execute_child` method in `subprocess.py` near the end.